# Dictionary with IF statement

Tags: python

Hey guys I am such a noob and I am learning to read code.
but I don't totally get why do I need to work with this parte of the code

```
start = True
with open('pairs.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        if start:
            print 'entre'
            start = False
            continue
```

if I don't use that is with that Boolean variable the code just does not work.
I mean just the IF not FOR

I get this **ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack**

** this is the code **

```
res = {}
start = True
with open('pairs.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        if start:
            print 'entre'
            start = False
            continue
        """ Lets asign index to ladies and matches """
        woman, matches = line.strip().split(': ')
        woman = int(woman)
        matches = map(int, matches.split(' '))
        res[woman] = matches
```

Thanks for your help :D

Comment: Look at the first line of `pairs.txt`. Is it the same as the other lines?

Comment: `line.strip().split(': ')` is returning a list with a single element when ': ' isn't found, yet `woman, matches =` is assuming the expression has exactly 2 elements

Comment: Stop using Python 2. It's out of service now; you should be using Python 3

Comment: you can add  `if ': ' not in line: print 'bad line ', line ` in the start of the loop to debug which lines of file are bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `if` statement is being used to skip the first line of the file, which is probably a header line. A simpler way to do that is to just read the first line before the loop.

The error you're getting is because some of the lines aren't in the form `woman: matches`, so `split()` isn't returning two values. Add code to check that the line contains the delimiter first.

```
res = {}
with open('pairs.txt', 'r') as f:
    f.readline()
    for line in f.readlines():
        if ': ' in line: # Check the line format
            # Lets asign index to ladies and matches
            woman, matches = line.strip().split(': ')
            woman = int(woman)
            matches = map(int, matches.split(' '))
            res[woman] = matches
```

Comment: amazing, I got it!!